# filtring data from firebase to angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

--my goal--

to filter my data and show it on the table
--expected results--

showing my data filterd

--what i tried--

```
 getData(){
    this.firebaseService.getUsers()
    .subscribe(result => {
      this.items = result;
      this.id_order_filltered_items = result;
      this.phone_filtered_items = result;
      this.heure_filtered_items = result;
      this.NOMchauffeu_filtered_items = result;

    })
  }
 ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
    console.log('hey',this.searchValue)
  }
searchByName(){
  let value = this.searchValue.toLowerCase();
  this.firebaseService.searchUsers(value)
  .subscribe(result => {
    this.NOMchauffeu_filtered_items = result;
    this.items = this.combineLists(result, this.phone_filtered_items);
  })

---
my service

 searchUsersByAge(value){
    return this.db.collection('commandes',ref =>
    ref.orderBy('phone').startAt(value)).snapshotChanges();
   }
```

i really appreciat the help
i am new to firebase

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure about what you are trying, but you could try something like this (haven't tested it)

commandes

```
export interface commandes{
    items ?: any;
    id_order_filltered_items ?:any
    phone_filtered_items ?: any
    heure_filtered_items ?: any
    NOMchauffeu_filtered_items?:any
  }
```

..

```
commandes: Commandes

 ngOnInit() {
    this.commandes = myService.searchUsersByAge(10).subscribe(x => {this.commandes = x; console.log('hey',this.commandes)} )
    
  }
```

MyService

```
 searchUsersByAge(value){
          return this.db.collection<commandes>('commandes', ref =>
                 ref.orderBy('phone').startAt(value)).snapshotChanges();)}
```

Comment: Sorry i will try to explain a bit after i showed the data in a table i puted a search button so i can filter the data but my filter didn't work i want to create a filter function so i can filter my data  when i type in my search input